# Configuring React webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found this code online to create a webpack for react.. what exactly is happening here? I need something like this to be able to use react right? I'm quite confused.

```
const path = require('path');

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, 'client-app.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: BUILD_DIR
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
        }],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is it asking me to please add some context? I am trying to add more details so that this question can be posted

Comment: This packages your JSX and ES6 code for the web with loaders.

Answer (score 0):

The code above does the following:

1. It resolves the `client` folder inside your projects folder and saves it to `SRC_DIR` and `BUILD_DIR`.
2. It tells `webpack` to look for a file named `client-app.js` in the resolved `client` folder from step 1.
3. It tells `webpack` to output the bundles Javascript into the `client` folder from step 1 with the file name `bundle.js`.
4. It tells `webpack` to look for any imported or required `.js` and `.jsx` files beginning at `client-app.js` inside your project folder (while excluding files from node_modules unless explicitly imported) and load them into the bundle using the `babel-loader` with the presets to compile the code from `es2015 react` to es5.